# Error running stored proc in Oracle - Cannot print cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, toad

I created the below script in hopes to standardize a reporting process:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure cba.ITEM_REPORT
 (date IN varchar2,  item IN varchar2, c1 in out SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN

OPEN c1 FOR
SELECT DISTINCT * from abc.ITEM_TRANS_TABLE
          WHERE
          DEAL.FEED_EFF_DATE = date
          AND DEAL.EDSF_SOURCE_SYSTEM_FEED_CODE = item;              
END;
/
```

I'm trying to run the stored proc with:

```
set serveroutput on size 100000;
variable rc refcursor;
exec EDSETL.STANDARDCOGNOS('31-jan-20', 'WSSTOR',:rc );
print rc;
```

When running the above I get the following error:

Unknown error: ORA-65535
Error Printing Variable "rc"

Can someone please help?

Comment: Your procedure names aren't even close to matching - `cba.ITEM_REPORT` vs `EDSETL.STANDARDCOGNOS`. Are you sure you're calling the procedure you created?

Comment: I've got a feeling Toad does this as `print :rc`, with the leading colon; but it's a (very) long time since I've used it...

Comment: I believe c1 needs to be define as OUT only. And I'd rename the date argument to something other than a reserved word, plus make sure the datatype matches DEAL.FEED_EFF_DATE or make sure to TO_DATE() it when comparing if appropriate.  No leave it up to Oracle to convert datatypes, do it explicitly.

Comment: Oh and by the way, where's "DEAL"?  Don't you mean "ABC"?